# How to query (hashed) Discord ID in MySQL and return user-defined name

Tags: mysql, discord.js, sequelize.js

I currently have a database of about 300 freely chosen names and corresponding Discord IDs.
I wish to make a discord bot that "checks" if a user already has a stored name on the database.

It should accept a Discord ID, and return the name that corresponds to the ID.
The problem is that the name is freely chosen and doesn't correlate with the discord tag or username.

For security reasons, the Discord IDs on the database are hashed. However, that poses one problem with salt.
Up until now, I mostly interacted with the database using PHP, where the same problem occured.
The main idea for logging pages seems to be:

- `SELECT password WHERE username = ?`
- comparing the hashed value with the entered password by hashing the latter

However, since the bot should return the **username**, this is troublesome. I cannot filter how many rows return since no filter can be applied, and performing every comparison would add up to minutes of waiting time.

Hashing the value and querying it also does not work, as the salt is randomised.
At the same time, somehow hashing without a salt would prevent this, since you can hash the id and literally compare it in a SQL query. But that of course causes a security issue with rainbow table attacks.

To sum up the problem, I have a list of IDs that should be hashed for security reasons, but they are not associated with any account, but simply correspond with a value. You should be able to enter an ID, and the database should return a username that corresponds to it (if it exists).

Is there a way to hash sensitive data, while also being able to compare it using a **SELECT WHERE** query, instead of being forced to **SELECT** everything and loop through every entry?

Some info that might help:
Mysql                        v5.7.23-23
The bot is created using     discord.js@14.6.0
Performing queries with      sequelize@6.25.3

Comment: If i understood it correctly the salt seems stateless and so its one way street and if thats the case i don't think there's a way to match it but this also brings us on -> how come you will be able to match it with select all and checking each record ?
If you do have salt, in that case you can just hash the input in code and then query it against the DB right ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha Well, up until now I've been using the `password_verify()` function in PHP, which accounted for salt. The problem with that function is the time it takes to complete, and is designed for a username/password system where you only return one hashed value to compare against.
As for 'having salt', I only seem to be able to find randomly generated salts, which prevent comparisons in queries. No matter what the original ID was, the salts differ.
Could you elaborate on "just hash the input in code"? Like a hard-coded salt?

Comment: Basically you need to have the salt stored somewhere to begin with comparing 2 values hashed using salt, so either have it stored somewhere and then use it while comparing or else i'm afraid you'll have to compromise on some other front.
How are you currently generating salt or what function you are using for hashing and in which language?

Comment: @HarshGundecha None yet, I did not want to commit to solutions that were impossible to complete. But I think I will go with bcrypt due to it being supported in sequelize and PHP.